# Why doesn't type narrowing work in useQuery in TanStackQuery?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-query

I want to use useQuery's isSuccess to do type narrowing, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
  const { data, isSuccess } = useQuery(["test"], () => Promise.resolve(5));

  if (isSuccess) {
    //If you hover your mouse over the data, the type is checked as number | undefined.
    data;  
  }
```

Comment: Well any value fetched from the back end is undefined until that API request has responded. So on the front end, `data` is undefined until the query returns a response. Since the query is async it doesn't block the front end while waiting for a response from the back end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine and is narrowed correctly in the latest version of TypeScript (4.9). Here is a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCKz1QJ4A0cAqhtrngPJgzAQB2qcAvnAGZQQhwDkAAjACGjIQGMA1gHoo6QaJgBaAI458PAFDq4cUQ1TwkAE0FCiwVAGVko0elRNWAXhRlVeABQBtAEQw7MbwBdIncASjhHAD44AAVOEHN0ADoZVAgAGwA3dHcAVlDQgG5NbWA2OHdzKxs7VHCELW04SUkASXK8CGQ4AAsIbKg4TuRBkC6MOH7cOBge9DhjUxm5mbwwefMdOYl0QzhBJnpkEAAjaYAfFHpDdDZgel2kxu1FwSa4LRa4AD0AfkbmEA).

TypeScript only added [control flow analysis for destructured discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) in version 4.6. If you are using an older version of TypeScript, you should not use destructuring if you want type narrowing to work:

```
const query = useQuery(["test"], () => Promise.resolve(5));

if (query.isSuccess) {
  // this is now of type `number`
  query.data;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect it to be because of the version of the TypeScript.